# Tap with two fingers for a "right-click" or secondary click

Tags: trackpad, multi-touch

On a Mac, I used to be able to secondary-click using a two-finger tap. Currently, I can only secondary-click using a two-finger click, not a tap.

[image]

Is there a way to alt-click using a two-finger tap instead of a click?

Comment: You didn't state what kind of Mac or what macOS version you're using.  I have a 2015 MBP running Mojave 10.14.4 and the 2 finger tap works as a secondary click.  I have the option `Click or tap with two fingers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 checkboxes in the top of the Preference pane you show as a screenshot. The third one, which you have unchecked, enables "tap to click" - turn this option on and you'll be set. If that one is off, you must click (rather than tap) for all other options shown. [image: Trackpad preference panel]

Comment: thank you, not sure why I didn't see this, I toyed with the settings for 10 minutes lol

Answer (score 1):

I have a MBP 2018 with Mojave on it and I have that same dialog like this:

[image: ss]

I find it easier to look at the trackpad options using the `defaults` command vs. navigating the dialogs that have become a confusing mess going from one version to another of macOS. On my system I have the settings like this:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad
{
    ActuateDetents = 1;
    Clicking = 1;
    DragLock = 0;
    Dragging = 0;
    FirstClickThreshold = 1;
    ForceSuppressed = 0;
    SecondClickThreshold = 1;
    TrackpadCornerSecondaryClick = 0;
    TrackpadFiveFingerPinchGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerPinchGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerVertSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadHandResting = 1;
    TrackpadHorizScroll = 1;
    TrackpadMomentumScroll = 1;
    TrackpadPinch = 1;
    TrackpadRightClick = 1;
    TrackpadRotate = 1;
    TrackpadScroll = 1;
    TrackpadThreeFingerDrag = 1;
    TrackpadThreeFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 0;
    TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture = 0;
    TrackpadThreeFingerVertSwipeGesture = 0;
    TrackpadTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture = 1;
    TrackpadTwoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture = 3;
    USBMouseStopsTrackpad = 0;
    UserPreferences = 1;
    version = 12;
}
```

I'd compare your settings with mine to see what's amiss. If you find one of the settings is different you can use `defaults` to change it as well.

#### Example

Here I'm merely cycling the values for the property `FirstClickThreshold` to illustrate how one can use `defaults` to write and then read values.

```
$ defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad | grep FirstClickThreshold
    FirstClickThreshold = 1;

$ defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad FirstClickThreshold 0
$ defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad | grep FirstClickThreshold
    FirstClickThreshold = 0;

$ defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad FirstClickThreshold 1
$ defaults read com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad | grep FirstClickThreshold
    FirstClickThreshold = 1;
```