# How do I tap on bottom right to trigger a secondary click?

Tags: trackpad

Similar to [Tap with two fingers for a "right-click" or secondary click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358592/tap-with-two-fingers-for-a-right-click-or-secondary-click) but I want tap bottom right for secondary click?

They only have the option for Click

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai). I use it to define actions for taps in corners of my trackpad, but it knows abut middle of top and bottom of trackpad. It can do taps, swipes and gestures with up to 5 fingers.  It is so configurable that what it does is only limited by your imagination or your ability to remember what you have configured.

This was also the answer to [Triple finger tap for middle click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7110/triple-finger-tap-for-middle-click?rq=1).